# Matlab function as Simulink block

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-cvst, matlab-coder

I tryed to write an Matlab function in Simulink.
My first func like this:

```
function y = fcn(u, v)
coder.extrinsic('detectSURFFeatures');
boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(u);
%scenePoints = detectSURFFeatures(v);
vBoxPoints = boxPoints.selectStrongest(100);
y = 0;
y = vBoxPoints;
```

But I see errors:
1. Attempt to extract field 'selectStrongest' from 'mxArray'.
2.Undefined function or variable 'vBoxPoints'. The first assignment to a local variable determines its class.
3. Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'detecting_cross/MATLAB Function/v' is a [400x239] matrix.
Pls, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data returned from extrinsic functions are mxArray types. If you want to get the values from these mxArrays you need to pre-declare them so that the result of extrinsic function can be auto-converted to that type. You can use something like

```
boxPoints = struct('selectStrongest',zeros(100,1));
```

before calling detectSUTFFeatures. If the mxArray does not match the one from the function, you will get a run-time error. Your errors 2 and 3 are because of the first problem.

Comment: Hi. Ok I'd try it:
'function y = fcn(u) 
coder.extrinsic('detectSURFFeatures', 'rgb2gray'); 
boxPoints = struct('selectStrongest',zeros(100,1)); 
img = zeros(150 , 200, 'uint8'); 
img(:) = rgb2gray(u); 
boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(img); 
y = zeros(100 , 1); 
y = boxPoints.selectStrongest(100);'
But there's didn't work.

Comment: I gave that line which creates struct as example. You should make it in a way to match your struct. What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: It get me error:
MATLAB expression 'detectSURFFeatures' is not of the correct class: expected 'struct', found 'SURFPoints'. Block MATLAB Function (#25) While executing: none

Comment: I want to repeat this example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/object-detection-and-tracking.html but in Simulink

Comment: It looks like vBoxPoints is a scalar double value. Since you are interested only in obtaining this value it may be easier for you to write another extrinsic function which takes boxPoints as input and returns this value.